# Monitor JBoss through SNMPv3

Tags: jboss, monitoring, snmp, jboss-eap-4.3.x

I am on a development team that is using JBoss EAP 4.3.0.GA_CP06. I need to be able to monitor JBoss using **SNMPv3**.

I understand I am able to use SNMP to monitor, but is it possible to monitor using v3 out-of-the box? If it is possible, what configurations need to be made to do this? If it is not possible, what external/other options are there for monitoring JBoss with SNMPv3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible "out-of-the-box". An external SNMP adapter is required (e.g. WebNMS, iReasoning).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `snmp-agent.sar` is in your deploy directory (which depends on which config you picked), then JBoss will be exposing SNMP information on port 1161 (see inside the `.sar` for additional configuration).

I don't recall if this is SNMPv3, though, or v2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Per requirements, I particularly need to know whether **v3** is supported. I can't seem to find much good information online concerning the SNMP version support.